# Confused about the scrollTo(int x,int y) method in Android

Tags: android, scroller

There is a scrollTo(int x,int y) method in the View class,but I don't know why the view scroll to the left only when the number of x is positive and negetive the view scroll to right. I thought just the opposite.
I'm not a native speaker,Sorry for my poor english!
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction of the scroll is not related to the sign of the `x` parameter for the `scrollTo` method.

This is your x axis:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------->
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  -7   -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

The `scrollTo(int x, int y)` method will scroll your `View` to a specific position.

Let's say the current `x` position of your `View` is `3`. If you do this:

```
scrollTo(1, 0);
```

You make the `View` scroll to the right, because the current value of `x` (`3`) **is greater** than the expected value (`1`).

Now, if you do this:

```
scrollTo(5, 0);
```

You make the view scroll to the left because the current value of `x` (`3`) **is lower than** the expected value (`5`).

To make it simple, the direction of the scroll for the `scrollTo` method **only** depends on the difference between the current and the expected values:

- If `expectedValue` < `currentValue` then scroll to right
- If `expectedValue` > `currentValue` then scroll to left

However, the reasoning that you had is correct for the `scrollBy(int x, int y)` method.

**EDIT**

Here is a more detailed explanation.

Let's say, again, that your `View`'s current `x` value is `3`. It means that the left border of your screen (for example) matches with the 3 value on the x axis, it can be seen as below:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------->
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  -7   -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
                                           ^
                                           |
                                      LEFT BORDER
```

Then you want to put your `View` to 7 on the `x` axis, it means that you want to put the value 7 to the left border of your screen:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------->
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  -7   -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
                                           ^               ^
                                           |               |
                                      LEFT BORDER       EXPECTED
```

The `LEFT BORDER` can't move as it is the left border of your screen. So the only solution is to move the `EXPECTED` position to the **left**. It's the same when the expected value is lower than the current one.

It's pretty complicated to explain this easily, hope you'll get it.

Comment: Thanks so much!u tell me the what it should be,But why?

Comment: What do you mean by why? What don't you understand?

Comment: "If expectedValue < currentValue then scroll to right
If expectedValue > currentValue then scroll to left"
why?

Comment: I got u approximately!
I can't tell you how grateful I am.